# Outlier detection for observations with sinusoidal relationship, incomplete information

Tags: least-squares, outliers, robust

I was looking for recommendations for an outlier rejection problem I find myself needing to solve.

I have a set of measurements (12 at a time) which vary sinusoidally according to
$$
d = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\cos\phi\\ \sin\theta\cos\phi\\ \sin\phi\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the measurement $d$ has accompanying $\theta$ and $\phi$ azimuth and elevation angles. These 12 measurements are in a grid spanning 4x7.5 degrees.

I've considered using something like RANSAC and solving the least squares problem, $Ax=b$, for the parameter vector $x=\begin{bmatrix}a &b &c \end{bmatrix}^T$. But solving this, and getting reliable values for $x$ requires that the measurements are distributed widely enough that all three parameters are observable. These 12 values for me are always closely grouped, meaning the least squares solution for $x$ likely has unobservable terms leading to an inaccurate solution.

I was curious if anyone had any recommendations for a method for finding outlier values for $d$?